# Firefox banking certificates

Tags: firefox, encryption, certification

I'm using online banking on Firefox that requires me to import my personal certificate into the browser I use.

Bank access is via their webpage, using pass and personal certificates. My question is, where does Firefox store my personal certifications and how safe are they? Is it done via passwords and keys applications?

Also what are my options to store the certificate on a USB stick and use it with Firefox when accessing bank? How do I achieve this if the bank page requires the personal certificate to be imported into a browser to access their page?

Answer (score 1):

> Where does mozilla store my personal certifications and how safe are they?

Those are stored in a sqlite database in files names `cert8.db` and `key3.db` inside your home folder in a hidden directory `.mozilla/firefox/*.default/`. And it is very safe.

> Is it done via passwords and keys applications?

It uses public and private key pairs. [You can read more about public-key cryptography standards here.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PKCS) [Mozilla uses PKCS #11](http://www.mozilla.org/projects/security/pki/nss/tools/modutil.html) (also known as "Cryptoki". An API defining a generic interface to cryptographic tokens (see also Hardware Security Module). Often used in single sign-on, Public-key cryptography and disk encryption[10] systems).

I do not believe these 2 are possible(?) No proof but I can not seem to find any method for this.

> Also what are my options to store the certificate on a USB stick and use it with mozilla when accessing bank?
>
> How do I achieve this if the bank page requires the personal certificate to be imported into a browser to access their page?

Comment: Can I just  move the files names cert8.db and key3.db to an encrypted partition and mount it everytime i need the certificate?

Comment: You can try. You could copy the whole ./mozilla/firefox/ over to the USB and mount that.

Comment: tried copying entire folder,but if I open mozilla a new instance with default user profile is created, so I would have to copy the original folder back to /home every time I wanted to access my certificate.
Same goes for the two files. If I copy them and then delete from this location, I have to copy them back everytime to use. 
Is it possible to change the default location for these two files?

Answer (score 0):

As Rinzwind said, the certificates are stored in the `.mozilla` directory in your home folder. I would not consider this "very secure" though, anyone who copies this folder automatically gets access to your certificate as they are not password-protected.

I suggest you to create a new Firefox profile as described in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/74004/6969). This allows you to separate your main browsing profile (cookies, add-ons, history, ...) from your banking profile (which could then be kept on an encrypted external disk.